# "I look forward to receiving your updates", is it right?

Tags: idioms, email

> I look forward to receiving your updates

Do native UK speakers use this kind of sentence holding for news from someone?

I don't know if it could be helpful, the context I am referring to is a bureaucratic process and I would say

> to keep me updated as soon as new documents are ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further context, I would say this formal response is appropriate in a *business* setting.

If the person is expecting only one issue to be updated then the singular form could be used. Normally, the issue(s)  would either be understood or mentioned previously in the correspondence.

> I look forward to receiving your update

For a slightly less formal approach

> I look forward [to receiving updates](https://www.google.it/search?q=receiving%20your%20update&oq=receiving%20your%20update&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22to%20receiving%20updates%22&tbm=bks&start=10) in the year/future ahead
>   ........................................................ in the coming months

The following is the **most common formal request** for any ***news***

> I-or-We look forward to hearing from you

The OP's second suggestion is nearly perfect, I would only add a *please* to make the request more polite.

> Please, keep me updated.

The OP could also add the following condition

> ............................... [as and when](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-and-when) the documents are ready, thank you.

---

There are many types of informal requests **for news** that are appropriate between friends, these are just three [off the top of my head](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off-the-top-of-your-head).

1. Let me know what's happening/going on
2. Don't forget to keep me updated
3. As soon as you get any info drop me a line

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have known the form "to hearing from you", but it seems more focused on the person than on the issue; am I right? Or it might be just a wrongly bias induced by the translation in my native language (italian)...

Comment: @Gabrer  Hello, I'm so  glad my answer helped you. The "*.... look forward to hearing from you*" is a very common way to conclude a formal type of correspondence. But you're right, the recipient  is usually an individual, and the focus is on him or her to *reply* and supply the requested information. But without proper context it's impossible to really know for sure.

Comment: I don't know if it could be helpful, the context I am referring to is a bureaucratic process and I would say to keep me updated as soon as new documents are ready.
Glad to helped you through your help! :)

Comment: @Gabrer context is so important, in any language, say: *"Please inform me* (OR *keep me updated*) *as and when the documents are ready, thank you*"